# x tick label style issue, anchor=east and text width command not working together

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I have a figure where one of my labels is very long. I would like this label to be split to two rows. Currently my code is like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=10 cm}
\begin{axis} [
symbolic x coords={0, Label 1, Label 2, This is a very very very long label, Label 4, Label 5, Label 6, Label 7,Label 8},
xtick={Label 1, Label 2, This is a very very very long label, Label 4, Label 5, Label 6, Label 7},
x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east, align=center},
axis lines*=left,
ymajorgrids = true,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.30)},anchor=north},
ymin=0,
ymax=175,
bar width=5mm,
ybar=-0.5cm, 
enlarge x limits={abs=0.6cm},
nodes near coords,        
every node near coord/.append style={color=black},
]
\addplot [red,fill=red] 
coordinates{ (Label 1,100) (Label 2,90) (This is a very very very long label,80) (Label 4,140) } ;
\addplot [blue,fill=blue]
coordinates{ (Label 5,80) (Label 6,25) (Label 7,66) } ;
\addlegendentry{Legend 1}
\addlegendentry{Legend 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this: [image]

Now if I try to change the x tick label style to be

```
x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east, align=center,text width=3.5cm}
```

This happens: [image]

So the anchor=east command doesn't seem to go along with the text width command. Other anchor commands like anchor=west, anchor=base seem to be working perfectly normal. Does anyone know why the anchor east command doesn't seem to work with the text width command and is there a way to go around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `x tick label`s are anchored to the east. But since you are giving `align=center` and `textwidth=3.5cm` the labels that are shorter will be aligned to the center with blank space to the right. Hence they stay bit away from the x-axis. To solve it align them to the right with `align=right` in

```
x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east, align=right,text width=3.5cm},
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=10 cm}
\begin{axis} [
symbolic x coords={0, Label 1, Label 2, This is a very very very long label, Label 4, Label 5, Label 6, Label 7,Label 8},
xtick={Label 1, Label 2, This is a very very very long label, Label 4, Label 5, Label 6, Label 7},
x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east, align=right,text width=3.5cm},
axis lines*=left,
ymajorgrids = true,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.30)},anchor=north},
ymin=0,
ymax=175,
bar width=5mm,
ybar=-0.5cm,
enlarge x limits={abs=0.6cm},
nodes near coords,
every node near coord/.append style={color=black},
]
\addplot [red,fill=red]
coordinates{ (Label 1,100) (Label 2,90) (This is a very very very long label,80) (Label 4,140) } ;
\addplot [blue,fill=blue]
coordinates{ (Label 5,80) (Label 6,25) (Label 7,66) } ;
\addlegendentry{Legend 1}
\addlegendentry{Legend 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]